# Quotient of a polynomial ring by a polynomial is equal to the direct sum of quotients by the roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Reading through Claudio Procesi's *Lie Groups: An Approach through Invariants and Representations*, I came across the following claim, stated without proof during the derivation of some properties of the Bezoutiant:

> Let $F$ be a field and let $f(X) \in F[X]$ be a monic polynomial. If $f(X) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} (X-a_i)^{h_i}$ for $a_i \in \overline{F}$, then
>   $$\overline{F}[X]/f(X) = \bigoplus\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \overline{F}[X]/(X-a_i)^{h_i}.$$

I suspect that this is something that should be obviously true, but no obvious isomorphism or algorithm for factoring $q(X) \in F[X]$ such that $$q(X)\pmod{f(X)} = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} q(X) \pmod{(X-a_i)^{h_i}}$$ suggests itself.

Comment: This is called the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Direct product, not direct sum!

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, e.g see [this Wikipedia entry on the PID case.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_principal_ideal_domains)

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew I was overlooking something simple..